# TFS 2017 Build Automatically kicks off and keeps failing

Tags: git, tfs, msbuild, bitbucket

I have a TFS 2017 server build, it is linked to a bit bucket\Git repo. 
The build is set to automatically kickoff when master changes. This works fine and also works fine if i manually kick off a build of master or a branch.

But i keep getting thse failed build that randomly kick off by **Project Collection Service Accounts**

They always fail with this error

> An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException:
>   this remote has never connected --->
>   LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: this remote has never connected 
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)  at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_ls(Repository repository,
>   RemoteHandle remote)  at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Repository.ListRemoteReferences(String url,
>   CredentialsHandler credentialsProvider)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(ExternalConnection
>   connection)  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(ExternalConnection
>   connection)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters,
>   Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2&
>   ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage).

These fails are always **Individual Continuous Integration**

But when i check into master which is the same user **Project Collection Service Accounts** it uses **Batched Continuous Integration** not sure if this makes a difference. This is happening on all my build definitions but only since i upgrade to TFS 2017, this did not happen on my previous version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by adding the Project Collection Service Accounts as a member of the endpoint administrators

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info：

> this remote has never connected at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)

This is a connection failing issue and since you have upgraded your TFS Server. You could give try to update the credentials of the **External Git Service endpoint**. (Delete the old one and create a new one) which may to the trick.

Beside if you are using [TFS2017.1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1#a-idvc-a-version-control-improvements), you could also use another option  for integrating TFS with Bitbucket-- [One-Time import of source code form Bitbucket](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2016/10/13/integrating-vsts-with-bitbucket/)  This is something very comfortable because you don’t have to worry about integration at all if you just use whatever TFS brings out of the box.

Comment: But it works when i manually queue a build or a merge a branch into master, so the credentials must work for the endpoint