# Builds on vsts failing(Polling exception)

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have run into this problem where my builds on vsts are failing. When I trigger them manually they work fine. Also when some new code is pushed, the continous integration feature works fine. However due to some reason builds are triggering automatically and failing for all definitions.[image]

As shown in the image as well, It doesn't even start and gives a failed message. How can I stop this. 
I am using VS2015.

Here is the error message:

> An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException:
>   this remote has never connected --->
>   LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: this remote has never connected 
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) in
>   F:_git\libgit2-for-skyrise\src\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line
>   154  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_ls(Repository repository,
>   RemoteHandle remote) in
>   F:_git\libgit2-for-skyrise\src\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line 2314  at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.ListRemoteReferences(String url,
>   CredentialsHandler credentialsProvider) in
>   F:_git\libgit2-for-skyrise\src\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Repository.cs:line 647  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(ExternalConnection
>   connection) in
>   F:\v2.0\A2_work\9\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line
>   19  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(ExternalConnection
>   connection) in
>   F:\v2.0\A2_work\9\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line
>   30  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters) in
>   F:\v2.0\A2\_work\9\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line
>   279  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters,
>   Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2&
>   ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in
>   F:\v2.0\A2_work\9\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line
>   217  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) in
>   F:\v2.0\A2_work\9\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\BuildPollingJobExtension.cs:line
>   100.

Comment: Do you mean all builds will be triggered automatically? What’s the result with newly created build definition? Where did you get that screenshot? Do you install some tool/extension? What’s related to VS2015?

Comment: Are you using External Git with CI enabled in the build definition?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yes.

Comment: @starain-MSFT CI is enables and are triggered on any change in repository. I recreated all build definitions, they keep triggering and failing randomly with the above error. Screenshot is taken from slack, that is connected with VSTS.

Comment: Do you use on premise build agent?

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996329/tfs-2017-build-automatically-kicks-off-and-keeps-failing/43085198#43085198

Answer (score 0):

A couple of fixes could be tried:
1. Update build agent by going to agentQueues on VSTS.
2. I was using remote source instead of bitbucket/ Github source to trigger the builds. Authenticating with Bitbucket using oauth resolved my issue.