# TFS 2017 CI Failing When Manual Build Works

Tags: git, tfs, gitlab

I am having the exact same issue as a previous question: [TFS 2017 Build Automatically kicks off and keeps failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996329/tfs-2017-build-automatically-kicks-off-and-keeps-failing).
The only difference is that I am connecting to a local GitLab repository rather than bitbucket. When I run the build manually it works perfectly fine but when the build is kicked off with CI as "[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts" it fails immediately with the error "this remote has never connected". I have added "[MyProject]/Endpoint Administrator" group as a member of the "Project Collection Service Accounts" group and it is still failing. Is there something else I could be missing?

Thanks for any of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure it's add the **Project Collection Service Accounts** as a member of the **Endpoint administrators** under your Service Endpoint, but not add "[MyProject]/Endpoint Administrator" group as a member of the "Project Collection Service Accounts" group.

(**Manage Server** > **Services** > Select your Service Endpoint (**GitLab**) > **Add** > **Add TFS group** > Select the **Project Collection Service Accounts** to add )[image]

**Update:**

Please follow below steps to add the **Project Collection Service Accounts** as a member of the **Endpoint administrators**:

Navigate to **Settings** > **Security** > Select **Project Collection Service Accounts** > **Member of** > **Add**, to add the [Project] **Endpoint Administrators**[image]

Comment: For TFS 2017 it won't let me do anything like that. "[MyProject]\EndPoint Administrators" has admin rights on the endpoint but I cant add the service account to the roles list on the endpoint, only add the service account to the endpoint administrators group.

Comment: @ChrisB. Please see the updates to add the Project Collection Service Accounts as a member of the project Endpoint administrators. Check the issue again after do that.

Comment: So have already tried to add it to Endpoint Administrator and I am still getting the same error. I also tried adding it to "Security Service Group" this morning and it still is failing on continuous deployment.

Comment: @ChrisB. Please try to add the agent service account and Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) to the role list on the endpoint directly (not the member of the endpoint administrator group). Then try it again.

Comment: So for whatever reason it won't let me add "Project Collection Service Accounts" to the endpoint roles. It adds it to the list then when i refresh it is no longer there. It did allow me to add "Project Collection Build Service" but even with this added it still is failing.

Comment: @ChrisB. I checked with the bitbucket at my side, everything works correctly. Please try to add the agent service account and your current account which will queue  the build as the Administrator role for the endpoint service. Then try it again. Also, you can try to delete the endpoint service and add it again with the correct credential. And you can also try the bitbucket to check if it has the same issue.

Comment: I have tried what you said and it is still failing with the same error. Like I noted this is GitLab server not bitbucket and like I said it is working fine if I request it manually. Can you think of any reason why I cant add "Project Collection Service Accounts" as an admin role to the endpoint? Is there any other security I might need to set on my build definition itself? I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: @ChrisB. "Project Collection Service Accounts" can't add as an admin role to the endpoint in TFS 2017, after adding "Project Collection Service Accounts" as the member of  "Endpoint Administrators", it should already be the endpoint Administrator role. Have you tried to reboot the local git server?